# How to use For Loop to `zip` a series of `.csv` files in a folder?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, zip, jupyter-lab

I have a bunch of `.csv` files in a folder (current folder `./`) that I would like to compress them via `zip` through a For Loop.

I am on Jupyter Lab and tried the following scripts:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./'):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        print(filename)
        !zip filename filename
```

But for some reason, it takes `filename` as a string equal to `filename` and not the value of it.

Any suggestions/thoughts?

Comment: Where is it taking filename to be a string? In the if statement, the print statement, or the zip statement?

Comment: zip statement, indeed

Comment: Have you tried using ZipFile? https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write

Comment: no, I have not. I was hoping `zip` can do the job in a For Loop :(

Comment: You can still use in a for loop. Just replace you zip line with a ZipFile.write() line

Answer (score 0):

To pass python variables to bash scripts one should use `$variable` format.

```
for filename in os.listdir('./'):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        filename_nosuffix = filename[:-4]
        !zip $filename_nosuffix $filename
```